# Azure functions and Web app with Azure SignaR

Tags: azure-signalr

I'm pretty new to Azure SignalR and SignalR in general, I'm currently using Azure SignalR(default) for my Web App to send simple notifications to React application. Now I need to send same type of messages from Azure function(dotnet isolated) to the same React application but I'm facing some difficulties to get it all working. I've read quite some documentation but I can't find any example of how to send messages properly from az function to existing SignalR in default mode. When I add .AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR("connection string") in functions startup I get exception that Azure signalR is not connected yet when I try to send a message

Just trying to find a right direction to look at, for now only found solutions to have 2 separate hubs for az function and web app and connect react app to both or send http requests from az function to web app and work with hub in web app but both seem to be quite shaky